# Laravel same URL with 2 method

Tags: laravel

I am using same URL (Get and Post ) but on submit button it using the get method not the post .
my is below :

```
  <form action="{{route('document.update', $document->id)}}" method="POST"
                            enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-action">
                            <input type="hidden" name="flag" class="flag" value="0">
                                @csrf
                                @method('PATCH')


<button type="submit"  class="btn btn-md btn-primary mr-1 btn-submit"
                                                        data-text="{{ __('save-all-changes') }}" name="post_action"
                                                        role="button" value="post_comment">{{ __('post-a-comment') }}
```

I need to take the post not the get , any idea?

Comment: could you please add your routes file

Comment: the routes are:

 Route::get('/documents/{$id}', 'DocumentController@show')->name('document.show');
 Route::post('/documents/{$id}', 'DocumentController@update')->name('document.update');

Comment: you are submitting your form with method `PATCH` which is not listed in your routes list

Comment: I changed  @method('POST') , but same problem  it is go the get not post

Comment: no need for @method at all

Comment: It would probably be better to keep `@method('PATCH')` and update the route to be `Route::patch(...)` (or `Route::match(['PUT', 'PATCH'], ...)`) instead so that it follows convention since this looks like an update route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem , since i disabled all input using

$("input").prop('disabled', true);

this has disable the _token and _method input , Change the Jquery sentence to be :

> $("input").not( ':input[type=hidden]').prop('disabled', true);

this fix the problem .